# Why is my ejs template not showing the associated data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs, web-development-server

I made a show page for inventory

```
<% inventory.products.forEach(function(product) { %>
        <div class="card">
            <img src="<%= product.image %>" alt="" class="card-img-top" />
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">
                    <%= product.name %>
                </h5>
            </div>
        </div>

        <% }) %>
```

but the page doesnt show any product images and name
(Screenshots of my [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmtId.png) and [db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbEKo.png))

the code for my inventory db is:

```
let mongoose = require("mongoose");

let inventorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  },
  author: {
    id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
    username: String,
  },
  products: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Product",
    },
  ],
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Inventory", inventorySchema);
```

Comment: could you add the code where you get inventories? `Inventories.find ...`

Comment: thanks i figured out i wasnt passing the products array properly

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clarified a little, did you require the exported module of the db on your page route and did you create your documents? From what i see,  you exported a mongoose model and I wonder if there was a creation of documents made out of the db model you just exported.

If you didn't create the documents,  what you are trying to do will not work.

You need to retrieve your array of products created out your schema from your database and assign the products as a key. Once that is done, use the ejs file you shared to loop through the products which should be fetched from the db.

I hope that is clear and helpful.